How to pass arguments between Tabs using AutoRoute and AutoTabsRouter in Flutter?
I am developing a Flutter application using AutoRoute and AutoTabsRouter for tab navigation. I need to pass arguments between tabs, but I am encountering issues with maintaining and updating these arguments as I switch tabs.Here is a simplified version of my setup:
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(page: LoginRoute.page, initial: true),
        AutoRoute(page: SearchCustomerRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(
          page: MainRoute.page,
          maintainState: false,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(page: HomeRoute.page, maintainState: false),
            AutoRoute(page: AddNewCustomerRoute.page, maintainState: false),
          ],
        ),
      ];
}

// main_screen.dart
@RoutePage()
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SettingsCubit, SettingsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AutoTabsRouter(
          lazyLoad: true,
          homeIndex: 0,
          inheritNavigatorObservers: true,
          routes:const [
             HomeRoute(),
             AddNewCustomerRoute(),
          ],
          builder: (ctx, child) {
            final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(ctx);
            return Scaffold(
              body: child,
              bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
                height: 70,
                selectedIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (index) {
                  tabsRouter.setActiveIndex(index);
                },
                elevation: 10,
                destinations: [
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.barcode_reader),
                    label: LocaleKeys.scan.tr(),
                  ),
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined),
                    label: LocaleKeys.addCustomer.tr(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// home_page.dart
@RoutePage()
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget implements AutoRouteWrapper {
  final OnboardingResponeModel? onboardingData;

  const HomePage({Key? key, this.onboardingData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();

// add_new_customer_page.dart
context.navigateTo(HomeRoute(onboardingData: state.onboarding));

When I try to navigate from the second tab ( AddNewCustomerRoute ) to the first tab passing arguments it's all good. Then if I switch tabs and get back to home page, the previously passed arguments is still there, although the home page disposed.
I want to be able to delete the previously passed arguments between tabs, as the AutoTabsRouter seems to kinda maintain some state, even though maintainState: false is explicitly set.
How can I pass arguments between tabs using AutoRoute and AutoTabsRouter in Flutter?

If I recall it right TabViews don't dispose their tab widgets once they are created. Why not store the data out side of the app and update the tabs everytime the data is changed?
